# Puzzled with this number theory/analysis problem

Tags: number-theory, metric-spaces

So, I am having this problem,

> let $N(x,y)$ be the greatest integer which $b^{N(x,y)}|x-y$ where $x,y$ are integers in $\mathbb{Z}$. Assume that $b \geq 2$. Show $d(x,y)=b^{-N(x,y)}$ is a metric.

Well, I can't reason to show the triangular inequality holds.
After giving up, the solution leaves me puzzled with this reasoning.

> Assume $x,y,z$ are distinct since otherwise, it is easy to show. Since $b^{min\{N(x,y),N(y,z)\}}$ divides both $x-y$ and $y-z$,

Halt. Stop. If I can get over this reasoning, the rest is fine with me, but how does the "smaller of the two $N(x,y),N(y,z)$ in the form $b^{N}$ qualify to divide BOTH $x-y$ and $y-z$"? I cannot reason for this one, I mean,
I have(let $N(x,y)=n,N(y,z)=m$)

> $$b^n|x-y, b^m|y-z$$

Which I can rewrite as $ab^n=x-y, cb^m=y-z$ but fiddling with the two equations still doesn't lead me to concluding that for whatever distinct $x,y,z$ the smaller of $n,m$ will allow $b^{n,m}$ to divide both $x-y,y-z$.

Can anyone prove this for me?

Comment: Suppose $m < n$. Then $x-y = ab^n = (ab^{n-m})b^m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $N(x,y) = m$ and $N(y,z) = n$ so that $x-y = b^m c$ and $y-z = b^n d$ where $b$ does not divide $c$ or $d$. (All symbols denote integers and $m,n \geq 0$.)
Assume without loss of generality that $m \leq n$. (If $m > n$, then change the names of $x$, $y$, and $z$ so that this is no longer the case.) Then

$$
    x-z = (x-y) + (y-z) = b^mc + b^nd = b^m(c + b^{n-m}d),
$$

where (since $m < n$ implies $n-m > 0$) we know $c + b^{n-m}d \in \mathbb{Z}$. This shows that $b^m \mid (x-z)$. Thus if $r = N(x,z)$ is the greatest integer $s$ such that $b^s \mid (x-z)$ then we must have that $r \geq m$. In other words $N(x,z) \geq \min\{N(x,y),N(y,z)\}$. Now derive the triangle inequality from this.

Comment: not a direct answer to my question but solves the overall issue as a solution, i find this easier as an argument. Helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: The displayed equation in my answer shows exactly why the smaller of the two powers of $b$ divides both differences. I thought that was what you were asking about, no? In any event, I'm happy this helped. `:)`

Comment: oh i meant, i wanted to know how the smaller of $n,m$ would allow $b^n$ or $b^m$ to divide both $x-y$ and $y-z$, i think you showed directly that the smaller divides $x-z$. Which is practically the ultimate goal, so yes, it definitely helped lots :D

Comment: @JohnTrail: If $k = \min\{m,n\}$, then $x-y = b^mc = b^k(b^{m-k}c)$ and $y-z = b^k(b^{n-k}d)$ where $m-k \geq m-m = 0$ and $n-k \geq n-n = 0$ by the definition of a minimum. So $b^{m-k}c$ and $b^{n-k}d$ are integers, so these factorizations show that $b^k$ divides both differences.